# Long lasting free web hosting

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

I am looking a free web hosting site which is long lasting. It is because one of the free web hosting which I have been using, have shutdowned their free service. I am looking for some web hosting which is big enough so that it won't die easily or charge money after a period of time.

It should support wordpress. It would be best to have python and php supported. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Those who run free hosting sites have to pay someone else, so they have to make money somehow. I think they must run on very thin margins, so are always going to be fragile. I don't think you're going to find one, as no-one's found a way to make lots of money out of free hosting.

Comment: Voting to close. This question is impossible. Even paid hosts sometimes shut down. If you expect to pay nothing, it just means you're taking a proportionally bigger chance. If you want to start demanding longevity, then start paying up. If you want as cheap as absolutely possible, start with [NearlyFreeSpeech](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Paul's comment should really be an answer.

You get what you pay for, expecting free hosting to provide wordpress/php/python *and* be reliable *and* expect it to be in for the long haul is quite an ask.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you may be better off finding a cheap host which will provide what you want, secure in the piece of mind that it will still be there in 12 months (give or take bad luck!)

Many places offer basic hosting packages for £2-3 a month.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't recommend a decent free host to you - (probably because there is no such thing, depending on our definitions of the word 'decent').

I've always made a point of paying for hosting in the past. Even if it's £1/month, once you've made that contract (by paying), you're entitled to the service or product they offered by law.

When developing websites you should always have source control and so on, so if you're SET on using a free host, simply re-deploy elsewhere whenever your free host shuts down or stops offering a free server.